# "codec can't encode character" error when I run "pipx install eth-brownie"

Tags: brownie, pipx

When I ran "pipx install eth-brownie", I got this error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts\pipx.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 779, in cli
return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command
return commands.install(
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
venv.install_package(
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
File "C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to ...
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring the answer from [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302540/14187006). You could clone the brownie repo, follow [eth-brownie docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html).